Strength of Retangular Steel Tube
I have a retangular steel (A36) tube that is 2x6 inches with a 5/16 inch wall and 11 feet long.  Can it center lift a 5000 pound weight attached evenly to its endpoints?  How much deflection will occur by this 5000 pound weigth?  (Converse: A 5000 pound mid-point weight on this beam supported at its ends.)
Its a moment of inertia is 18.2 in^2:
MI = (2 * 6^3 - 1.375 * 5.375^3) / 12      = 18.21
Deflection of this beam, center lifting a 5000 pound load:
Deflection = 132^3 * 5000 / (48 * 29 * 10^6 * 18.21)    = 0.454"
Are these calculations correct?
What is the maximun weight this bar can support before being permanently deformed?

Start here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/beam-stress-deflection-d_1312.html

Lifting rigs that are potentially lethal (2.5 tons is potentially lethal) need a factor of safety of 10 in Australia, and are annually checked to 4. Your beam fails both of those tests woefully. Also, how do you stop the beam from toppling over?

The max tensile stress on the beam is M*y/I, which must be less than the yield stress (36ksi) with a safety factor.
